# How to run /bin/bash in a docker container?

Tags: bash, docker, exec, bin

How to run `/bin/bash` in a docker container that was started with the `-d option`, for example:

```
sudo docker run -P --name test-cnt3 -d base-tst:0.1?
```

I really need a console in the container and I already despaired of running it

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use [docker exec](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/exec/) to run a command in an already running container, use `-it` to create a new interactive pseudo-TTY:

```
docker exec -it test-cnt3 /bin/bash
```

Answer (score 3):

```sh
docker exec -it container-name /bin/bash
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use docker-composer or Dockerfile look at [Entrypoint & CMD](http://www.johnzaccone.io/entrypoint-vs-cmd-back-to-basics/)

And to connect use 
`sudo docker attach awesome-container`

Answer (score 0):

In my case, `docker exec -it test /bin/bash` gave me

```
Error response from daemon: Container f63bba8... is not running
```

When I tried

```
docker start test
```

the container started, but trying exec again threw the same error as before.

In the end, I had to enter

```
docker run -it test /bin/bash
```

This starts the bash right before the container stops.